# Get the first and second objects from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of `Person` objects. How can I get the first and second `Person` objects that meet a certain criteria from `List<Person> People` using `LINQ`?

Let's say here is the list I've got. How can I get the first and second persons that are over 18 that is James and Jodie.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int age;
}

var People = new List<Person>
{
   new Person {Name = "Jack", Age = 15},
   new Person {Name = "James" , Age = 19},
   new Person {Name = "John" , Age = 14},
   new Person {Name = "Jodie" , Age = 21},
   new Person {Name = "Jessie" , Age = 19}
}
```

Comment: @Red-arrower! The red-arrow is ridiculous! And to tell the truth I don't care one bit about the reputation. I'm here just for asking and learning :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var topTwo = People.Where(a => a.Age > 18).Take(2).ToArray();

Person p1, p2;
if (topTwo.Any())
{
   p1 = topTwo[0];
   if (topTwo.Count > 1)
       p2 = topTwo[1];
}
```

Comment: @PaulB You are most certainly correct

Comment: @DavidPilkington Thanks David, can I get the answer in two different variables? p1 and p2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'Take()' function here.

In your case, the following code will get the first 2 elements:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int age;
}

var People = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Name = "Jack", Age = 15},
    new Person {Name = "James" , Age = 19},
    new Person {Name = "John" , Age = 14},
    new Person {Name = "Jodie" , Age = 21},
    new Person {Name = "Jessie" , Age = 19}
}

People.Take(2);
```

The following code will get you the first 2 element with an age of 18:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int age;
}

var People = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Name = "Jack", Age = 15},
    new Person {Name = "James" , Age = 19},
    new Person {Name = "John" , Age = 14},
    new Person {Name = "Jodie" , Age = 21},
    new Person {Name = "Jessie" , Age = 19}
}

People.Where(x => x.Age > 18).Take(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstTwo = People.Where(a => a.Age > 18).Take(2);
```

Comment: Is not it the same answer as earlier posted by @David Pilkington.